# Visual Studio, library source when debugging

Tags: visual-studio

Just maybe trivial, maybe stupid question.

I have two solutions:

1) The main app
2) The sets of libraries

The first solution is accessible via the SourceSafe with the dll files(from the 2 solution) placed in its lib directory.

In order to debug the main app with the ability to jump to the source code of the libraries from the 2 solution Do i have to add the projects from 2 to 1? And Is it the only one option?

Even if I added (if it is possible to add with omitting certain projects in the SC) projects from 2 to 1 solution, I would have to change dll references in the app which is controlled via SourceSafe and I would mess it up for my colleagues.

What Can I do?

Comment: Did you ask your colleagues what the standard practice is in your place for handling this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To debug all you need is that all third-party dlls have their corresponding pdb in the same directory. When you step into a third-party function for which you have pdb, Visual Studio will prompt you for the source,  At this time you may browse to a local or network share where you have a the third-party source.

Comment: OK will try it, but how can i open the source of my referenced dll) to set the breakpoint?

Comment: Step into the function once...browse for the cpp and then you can set break points as you wish in other functions.

Comment: You can also do **Debug Menu->Break Point->New Breakpoint**. Enter the function like  **Foo::MyFunction** which will set the break point as well

Comment: Well, it works great however He has found the source code without my help. Where is the information stored with the source path? How has he done it?

Comment: Ok, probably in the pdb file :)

Comment: The pdbs have the filepath of the source hard coded in them by default. If on the machine that you are debugging the source code is at the same location, no prompting is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The place I used to work for used [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) to step through external DLLs.  It's a Visual Studio add-on that uses reflection to allow you to debug through the source code of .NET binaries (actually their MSIL reversed equivalents) and is pretty simple and efficient when it comes to non-obfuscated code.

Comment: @Hans Not necessarily, he obviously has access to the solution for the libraries but he's definitely referencing them in his main app.  Considering this, it would be trivial to step into the libraries using Reflector where he'd need to actually do something else to get the debugger to take into account the source code in the other solution.